# Solidity: call to other contract and check-effects problem

Tags: solidity

I'm struggling with following problem:

In the main contract I have this:

```
 function doSomething() view public onlyAdmin
 {
     require(!myOtherContract.isActive());
     // other stuff
 }
```

and the contract I'm calling has:

```
 function isActive() public view returns(bool)
 {
     return active;
 }
```

and I'm getting the warning:

> Potential Violation of Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern in
>   *MyToken.doSomething()*:
>   Could potentially lead to re-entrancy vulnerability. 
> *Note:*
>   Modifiers are currently not considered by this static analysis.

How can I make it correctly to hide the warning?

Answer (score 1):

It's not because you have a warning that you should do everything to "hide" it.

Read more carefully the warning.

> Note: Modifiers are currently not considered by this static analysis.

And this is your function `function doSomething() view public ---> onlyAdmin <---`. As the note said, it doesn't and didn't take in account the modifier, which is `onlyAdmin` here. So, by restricting the access to this function, you will be protected from unauthorized individuals trying to exploit whatever re-entrancy bug you potentially have.